# How do I store more than one user entered integer without using an array in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, memory, mips, mars-simulator

My question is; How do I store more than one user entered input into a variable without creating an array? When I run the code as I have posted here I get the error "store address not aligned on word boundary." Variable one is store1, variable two is store2. I want to store both separately entered integers into store1, and store2 respectively.

```
.data

store1: .byte 4                     #Stores data entered by user
store2: .byte 4                     # "                        "
msg: .asciiz "Enter your first decimal number: "
msg2: .asciiz "Enter your second decimal number: "
.text

main:

la $a0, msg #Displays msg
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5   #Prompts user to enter an integer
syscall

la $t0, store1  #Loads user input into store1
sw $v0, store1  #Stores user input into store1

la $a0, msg2    #Displays msg2
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5   #Prompts user to enter another integer
syscall

la $t1, store2    #My error occurs here 
sw $v0, store2    #If I delete these 3 lines the code compiles with no errors
syscall

li $v0, 10  #Cleanly exits the program 
syscall
```

Comment: You only allocated a byte. If you intend to store bytes, use `sb` not `sw`. Conversely, if you want words, use `.int` or whatever is equivalent in mars.

Comment: Understood. Using ```sb``` corrected the issue. Along with also changing ```.byte 4``` to ```.int 0``` Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`.byte 4` is one byte with the value 4, not four bytes (a word).  So they can't both be word-aligned.  You can see this by using the debugger to look at memory contents.

Perhaps you were looking for `.skip 4` if MARS allows that GAS pseudo-instruction.

Or like Jester said just use `.int 0` or `.word 0`